# Defining one to zero relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a relationship that I'm not sure how to define, I'm quite new to SQL so I might have it wrong.

I have an `Account` which looks like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public LiveCurrencyInfo CurrencyInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And LiveCurrencyInfo:

```
public class LiveCurrencyInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal USD { get; set; }
}
```

`Account` needs to have a link to a single `LiveCurrencyInfo` entity.

`LiveCurrencyInfo` exists as a completely separate entity which doesn't depend on anything else - as it's defined.

Is this a 1..0 relationship?

I tried defining it like this but the syntax is wrong:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Account>()
        .HasRequired(l => l.CurrencyInfo)
        .Map(m =>                        //Can't call .Map here
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("AccountId");
            m.MapRightKey("LiveCurrencyInfoId");
            m.ToTable("UserAccountLiveCurrencyMapping");
        });
}
```

*Edit*

I think the tables would look like the following:

```
Accounts         LiveCurrencyInfo         UserAccountLiveCurrencyMapping

Id | Username    Id | USD                 AccountId | LiveCurrencyInfoId
---+---------    ---+------               ----------+-------------------
20 | User_1      39 | 1.0                 20        | 39
```

Comment: Shouldn't LiveCurrencyInfo have an AccountId? Possibly as its primary key?

Comment: No - LiveCurrencyInfo is a completely seperate entity from account and exists independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a 1..0 relationship?

First you need to define the relationship ends (from -> to). But no, there is no such relationship at all.

According to your explanation, the relationship from `LiveCurrencyInfo` to  `Account` is `1 -> 0..1`. Hence by EF terms `LiveCurrencyInfo` is the **principal** end and `Account` is the **dependent** end. Since as I understand both entities should have independent PKs, then `Account` would need FK column referencing `LiveCurrencyInfo` PK.

The fluent setup is as follows (in order to make `Map` and other relationship fluent APIs available, you need first to complete the relationship ends definition started by `HasXyz` with the appropriate `WithXyz`):

```
mb.Entity<Account>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.CurrencyInfo)
    .WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("LiveCurrencyInfoId"));
```

Comment: I think this is nearly it - my `Accounts` table now has a column `LiveCurrencyInfoId` which maps to the correct entity in the `LiveCurrencyInfo` table. 

The only issue is that when I get the `Account` entity, the `CurrencyInfo` property is `null`

Comment: Got it, had to change `public LiveCurrencyInfo CurrencyInfo { get; set; }` to `public virtual LiveCurrencyInfo CurrencyInfo { get; set; }`. Thanks